# How to end the node js app and kill the terminal

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, package.json

I am using the below script in my package.json to start the node js app and perform the test simultaneously. To achieve this I used the concept of `npm concurrently`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "set NODE_ENV=dev && node server.js",
    "local": "set NODE_ENV=local && node server.js",
    "test": "set NODE_ENV=test && mocha --timeout 10000 --exit --reporter mocha-junit-reporter",
    "mochatest": "concurrently \"set NODE_ENV=local && node server.js\" \"set NODE_ENV=test && mocha --timeout 10000 --exit --reporter mocha-junit-reporter\""
```

So whenever I want to perform the test I will run the command `npm run mochatest` which will start my app and perform the test but to terminate the batch job I am using `Ctrl + C` . Is there a way to include a command to stop the job after a particular timeout.

My output window:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://mochajs.org/#command-line-usage) you can use `--exit` to "Force Mocha to quit after tests complete"

So `mocha --timeout 10000 --reporter mocha-junit-reporter --exit` should works.

I have this line:
`cross-env NODE_ENV=testing mocha tests --timeout 4000 --reporter mochawesome --exit`
and works fine.

Edit:

I've seen you run server and tests. Your terminal will not ends because server process is still running.
You don't need to start your server manually, `mocha` will start if you use something like:

```js
var app = require('...');


it('...', function(done) {
    request(app)
        .get('...')
        .expect(...).then(response => {
            assert.(...)
            done()
        })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to end the process use CTRL + C.